Sending a signal from a QThread closes the program
Python 3.11, PyQT6 GUI app, testing on Windows 10. I have a QThread doing some background work, and I'm trying to report progress back via a custom signal:
class TheWindow(QMainWindow):

    #...

    def on_menu_item(self):
        class MyThread(QThread):
            def __init__(self, parent):
                QThread.__init__(self, parent)
                self.progress = pyqtBoundSignal(int)

            def run(self):
                try:
                    for i in range(1000):
                        self.progress.emit(i)
                except Exception as exc:
                    pass

        th = MyThread(self)
        th.progress.connect(lambda i:print(i))
        th.start()

When the thread is invoked, the program crashes with no error message in the debug console and no exception caught. Commenting out the connect/emit lines removes the crash. What am I doing wrong?

Signals must be declared at class level. Move that progress definition in the main class indentation and change to pyqtSignal.

Worked. Make an answer.

No need for that, acceptable duplicates already exist, and the PyQt documentation about Signals and Slots also explains their proper usage.
